# UIButton with rounded rects and custom backgroundImage when highlighted

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

The problem is that my button doesn't get displayed correctly when highlighted. I'd like the background image to be blue, not opaque. The code I use is presented below.

```
self.button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
self.button.layer.borderColor = self.button.tintColor?.CGColor
self.button.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
self.button.layer.masksToBounds = true

self.button.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
self.button.setBackgroundImage(self.imageWithColor(self.button.tintColor!, size: self.button.bounds.size), forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
```

And the method for getting an image with a color.

```
func imageWithColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, true, 1.0)
    color.setFill()
    var bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)
    UIRectFill(bounds)

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return image;
}
```

Comment: is 'UIButtonTypeCustom' set as the button type?

Comment: Thank you very much! I totally forgot of changing its type! :D